# animated scroll to a specific position vertically using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Hey guys I am quite a newbie to JS.
I am wording on a vertical image scroller.
Now, I am using this code to scroll to  LI from left to right and the page is scrolled till centre of that Li reaches.
Now I want to integrate this functionality to a vertical scroller.
I have 6 divs set up and when I click on a thumb the li's should be scrolled to that position.
here is my horizontal code for it.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/p45fu/)

```
$('html, body').animate({                    
scrollLeft: ((thisImg.offset().left)-windowWidth+imagewidth)}, 1300);});
```

I trid scrollToTop but it didnt work.
Please tell me how to fix it.
Please see my fidde.
And i also wanted the crimson list items to capture 100% width and height. How should I do that.
thanks.
Ps: I want to achieve something like this [**Demo Site**](http://thelifelessordinary.co.uk/)

Answer (score 1):

@designerNProgrammer, It's generally good practice to make things in your site work without depending on jQuery/Javascript. You can then progressively enhance these features using jQuery/Javascript. This is how I would approach the vertical window scrolling using jQuery:

First, I'll add some anchor tags to the `#thumbs li's` that point to id's I set up on the `#fullList li's`. This HTML works without Javascript.

```
<ul id="thumbs">
    <li><a href="#one">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#four">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#five">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#six">6</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="fullList">
    <li id="one">1</li>
    <li id="two">2</li>
    <li id="three">3</li>
    <li id="four">4</li>
    <li id="five">5</li>
    <li id="six">6</li>
</ul>
```

Now we can use this existing/functioning code to progressively enhance the window scrolling with animation.

```
$(function() {
    $("#thumbs li a").click(function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();
        var elId = $(this).attr('href');
        var elPos = $(elId).offset().top;

        $('html, body').animate({                    
            scrollTop: elPos
        }, 1300);
    });
});
```

Set up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/k2ape/2/

Your responsive issue seems like a different question in relation to this question's title. That's why I didn't answer that. I'd submit a new question on SO for your responsive issue and word the title differently. You'll get a lot more responses.

Answer (score 0):

You were so close, it's actually just `scrollTop` not scrollToTop. This works for me:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#thumbs li").click(function() {
        var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width()/2,
            index = $(this).index(),
            thisImg = $("#fullList li:eq("+index+")"),
            imagewidth = thisImg.width()/2;
```

```
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: thisImg.offset().top
    }, 1300);
});
```

});

If you add a normalize.css and remove the margin from the li that should put the li to 100%. In the fiddle I didn't add a normalize, just set html and body to have 0 margin or padding.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maxinacube/6Y3WX
Normalize: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css

Comment: Can you make me a fiddle?

Comment: How can i make crimson Li 100%?

Comment: it's not 100% in with and height. not in height especially. i want it responsive just like the demo link above.

Comment: why am i not abl to set height to 100%?

Comment: Change the height in your CSS from 600px to 100% on the li's

Comment: ok now if i want to add a picture it should fit the full width and height right just like vertical scroller  gallery!